# Make the 'autobid' command stop the timer in the 'auction' command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have some code here that starts an auction with a timer with the use of a command.

Everything works correctly in it.

Under the `auction` command is an `autobid` command.

What I am trying to do is get the `autobid` command to completely stop the timer in the `auction` command, therefore ending the auction.

I have tried multiple methods including globals. I as well looked for my problem for quite a while, I can't seem to find a solution.

What I learned so far:

- the code doesn't throw an error,
- the `autobid` command does make the bot say what it is supposed to say,
- the `autobid` just doesn't stop the countdown in the `auction` command.

Could anyone help me with this or enlighten me on what I am doing wrong?

Updated code:

```python
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Mods")
async def auction(ctx, member: discord.Member, message1, number, number2, num: int, number4):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.message.author
    auction = discord.Embed(title='Auction Host: ', description=(member.mention), color=0x00ff00)
    auction.add_field(name='Cards/Items: ', value=(message1), inline=False)
    auction.add_field(name='Starting Bid: ', value=(number), inline=False)
    auction.add_field(name='Increment: ', value=(number2), inline=False)
    auction.add_field(name='Time Left: ', value=(num), inline=False)
    auction.add_field(name='Auto Bid: ', value=(number4), inline=False)
    message = await bot.say(embed=auction)
    perms = discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages=True)
    server = bot.get_server("459456116208959492")
    rank = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name='Members')
    await bot.edit_channel_permissions(channel=ctx.message.channel, target=rank, overwrite=perms)
    await bot.say("@here")
    if num > 10801:
        return await bot.say("I don't think I'm allowed to go above 3 hours!")
    elif num <= 0:
        return await bot.say("Can't be zero or negative.")

    id = ctx.message.channel.id
    if running.get(id, 0) > 0:
        # if the countdown while loop is already running,
        # don't start another one in the same channel
        return await bot.say("Already running.")

    running[id] = num

    while True:
        running[id] = running[id] - 1
        if running[id] <= 0:
            auction3 = discord.Embed(title='Auction Host: ', description=(member.mention), color=0x00ff00)
            auction3.add_field(name='Cards/Items: ', value=(message1), inline=False)
            auction3.add_field(name='Starting Bid: ', value=(number), inline=False)
            auction3.add_field(name='Increment: ', value=(number2), inline=False)
            auction3.add_field(name='Time Left: ', value="Auction Over!", inline=False)
            auction3.add_field(name='Auto Bid: ', value=(number4), inline=False)
            await bot.edit_message(message, new_content=None, embed=auction3)
            perms = discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages=False)
            server = bot.get_server("459456116208959492")
            rank = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name='Members')
            await bot.edit_channel_permissions(channel=ctx.message.channel, target=rank, overwrite=perms)
            break

        auction2 = discord.Embed(title='Auction Host: ', description=(member.mention), color=0x00ff00)
        auction2.add_field(name='Cards/Items: ', value=(message1), inline=False)
        auction2.add_field(name='Starting Bid: ', value=(number), inline=False)
        auction2.add_field(name='Increment: ', value=(number2), inline=False)
        auction2.add_field(name='Time Left: ', value="{} seconds".format(running[id]), inline=False)
        auction2.add_field(name='Auto Bid: ', value=(number4), inline=False)
        await bot.edit_message(message, new_content=None, embed=auction2)
        await sleep(1)

    await bot.say(member.mention + " your auction of " + str(message1) + " has ended!")



@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def autobid(ctx, number6, member: discord.Member = None):
    running[ctx.message.channel.id] = 0
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.message.author

    await bot.say(str(ctx.message.author.mention) + ' has won the auction with an autobid of: ' + str(number6).format(member))
```

Comment: Note: you should almost **never** raise `BaseException`. That can most likely be the cause of your problem since I don't believe discord.py handles BaseException. Use `return` instead.

Comment: Oh, small mistake on my part. I corrected the def setup(bot) part. However, I also corrected __raise BaseException__ with __return__ , it still seems to do the same thing as before.

Comment: Your code is pretty long to debug by reading (though it's quite clear that `counter` isn't being used and it's a local variable in two commands), can you provide a [mcve]? From what I can comprehend from your question, you basically want the `autobid` command to be a "stop" command that terminates `action` command's while loop. This isn't a simple task since you'll need to create a dict that maps a channel to a boolean value, and create a check in `action` that `break`s if the boolean value evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If context described in my comment portrays your situation:

> From what I can comprehend from your question, you basically want the
>   `autobid` command to be a "stop" command that terminates `action`
>   command's while loop.

Here's a simple "mock" code that you can learn from and adapt into your actual code. The example consists of two commands: `.run` and `.stop`. `.run` will initiate a infinite messaging loop, and `.stop` will stop that loop. This is just a base framework so you will need to make changes to make it fit your needs.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncio import sleep

bot = commands.Bot('.')
running = {}


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def run(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    if running.get(channel.id, False): 
        # if the infinite running while loop is already running, 
        # don't start another one in the same channel
        return await bot.send_message(channel, "already running")

    running[channel.id] = True
    while running[channel.id]:
        # prints a message every second until `.stop` is typed
        await bot.send_message(channel, "still running")
        await sleep(1)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def stop(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    running[channel.id] = False
    await bot.send_message(channel, "the loop had been stopped.")


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

---

Another example:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncio import sleep

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
running = {}


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def countdown(ctx, num: int):
    if num > 10800:
        return await bot.say("Too long.")
    elif num <= 0:
        return await bot.say("Can't be zero or negative.")

    id = ctx.message.channel.id
    if running.get(id, 0) > 0:
        # if the countdown while loop is already running,
        # don't start another one in the same channel
        return await bot.say("Already running.")

    running[id] = num

    while True:
        running[id] -= 1
        if running[id] <= 0:
            # do something when counter's at zero
            break

        # do something...
        await sleep(1)

    await bot.say("Done.")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def stop(ctx):
    running[ctx.message.channel.id] = 0
    await bot.say("The countdown had been stopped.")


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

---

I made the previous codes to be channel independent, if you don't want it (don't know why wouldn't you not want to):

```
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncio import sleep

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
running = 0


@bot.command()
async def countdown(num: int):
    if num > 10800:
        return await bot.say("Too long.")
    elif num <= 0:
        return await bot.say("Can't be zero or negative.")

    if running > 0:
        # if the countdown while loop is already running,
        # don't start another one in the same channel
        return await bot.say("Already running.")

    running = num

    while True:
        running -= 1
        if running <= 0:
            # do something when counter's at zero
            break

        # do something...
        await sleep(1)

    await bot.say("Done.")


@bot.command()
async def stop():
    running = 0
    await bot.say("The countdown had been stopped.")


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: I have been tweaking around with this code for quite some time. I can't seem to get it to work to my liking. In your code, you have a _True_ statement in the first command, and a _False_ statement in the second command. What I need is a _True_ and _False_ statement in the first command, and a _False_ statement in the second command, making the _False_ statement in the first command be called whenever the second command is called. I can't get the _False_ statement in the first command to work correctly. I simplified my code a bit to help. https://gyazo.com/2f97015530664e4fa513cb40a57064d3

Comment: @Skeletontrain added another example for what seems like your screenshot wanted. Please don't post picture of code in the future, thanks.

Comment: Oh, I only posted it as a picture because it wouldn't fit in a comment, I apologize for that. I'll test this code out and mess around with it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I updated the code, it now stops the timer in the auction command, thanks to you. However, now the formatting of the timer is messed up. The formatting of the timer now shows, _{'XXXXXXXXXXX': num} seconds_. The "XXXXXXXXX" part is showing the server ID. _Num_ shows and counts down the number as it should, however it should be formatted as _num seconds_. It's showing the server id due to the _[id]_ part in _running[id]_, I attempted to change this, and it did take away the server ID from showing in the countdown, however it then broke the _autobid_ command. Making it not stop the timer.

Comment: @Skeletontrain to show the countdown always use `running[id]`, you get what you got by formatting `running`. Anyways, if you must use one counter, I added an example.

Comment: Oh my, I missed that. It is now working and I updated the code in my question to the updated working code for anyone that might come across the same problem. I greatly appreciate your help! Thank you!